# Position Fixed Navigation Bar at Bottom of Screen

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive-design

Using Angular I have a horizontal navigation bar that I need to be fixed such that if I am scrolling up and down in the viewport the bar stays fixed at the bottom of the screen.

Here is the CSS code I have for the bottom navigation bar element:

```
.bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 65px;

  top: 90%;
  width: 90%;
}
```

The navigation bar behaves as desired, but I manually have to adjust the top and width properties to get the element to fit perfectly on the page. Of course that doesn't work when the resolution/screen size for the viewer changes and the element doesn't fit perfectly. See below for an example of trying to fit the element onto the page:

[image]

Is there a way to change the CSS to make the navigation bar fit perfectly on the page and also stay fixed? I can get the positioning to work fine if I change the position to absolute or sticky, but then it doesn't stay in one place when I scroll up or down on the viewport.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Does referencing from **bottom** work instead of **top**?

```
.bottom-bar {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 65px;
  bottom: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.bottom-bar{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;  // adjust the percentage if needed
}
```